# How do I log out of askubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion

How do I log out of  askubuntu.com ?

I'm on a shared machine login/user and I don't want to blow away all the cookies in the browser.

EDIT:
The answer below is perfect, but so you know, the 'duplicate question' is ["How do I log out of the Ubuntu website after creating a Stack Exchange account?"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14112/455406).

Comment: This is a question for meta.